# How to capture enter key press on a Html.TextBoxFor and call a jQuery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to fire an event to a function on a HTMLhelper textbox when the user key press enter. The following block of code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Search.EmployeeID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Search.EmployeeID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customEmployeeID", @onkeypress = "keypresshandle(event);" })

function keypresshandle(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Enter was pressed was presses");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this how it actually is in the view code? without script tags?

Comment: If the function is in the same page as the html, please show the whole page.  If the function is elsewhere, please show that full script and how it is called in the view.

Answer (score 0):

this is how `@Html.TextBoxFor` renders the control, e.g.:

Razor View:

```
@model Student
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Html Result:

```
<input class="form-control" 
        id="StudentName" 
        name="StudentName" 
        type="text" 
        value="John" />
```

I'd suggest you to go through [Html Helpers](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/html-helpers) to strengthen your concept of how it works.

As long as the input control tag has `name="propName"` which matches with modal object property, your controller obj parameter will receive its value. If you are having trouble generating controls using `@Html.TextBoxFor` then use the way of legends do it:

```js
function someFunction(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("omg you pressed the Enter key. How dare you!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="StudentName" id="StudentName" onkeypress="someFunction(event);" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@* use htmlAttributes keyword *@

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Search.EmployeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onkeypress = "keypresshandle(event);" } })
```

@* please put script tag here *@

```
<script>
    function keypresshandle(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Enter was pressed was pressed");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the onkeypress event didn't work. The onkeydown worked. Here is the code:

```
<input id="myHostName" autocomplete="on" class="txtHostname" type="text" onkeydown="ThisIsEnter(event);" />

<input name="SubmitButton" id="Submitbtn" type="submit" value="SearchHostAttributes" class="myButton" />

<script>
function ThisIsEnter(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("Submitbtn").click();
        }
    }
</script>
```